# Find an analytic function greater that a given continous function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ be a continuous fonction.

Can we prove the existence of an analytic function, $g: \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R} $ such that $f < g $  ?

The best I can obtain is a $C^{\infty}$ function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's rephrase the problem as: given a sequence of positive numbers $(A_n)_{n=-\infty}^\infty$, construct a real-analytic function $g$ such that $g\ge A_n$ on $[n,n+1]$. I will construct an entire function $g:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ with this property:
$$
g(z) =\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}A_n e^{k_n (1-(z-n)^2)}  \tag1
$$
where $k_n>0$ is chosen so that $A_n e^{-k_n/2}<2^{-|n|}$.

First of all, for $x\in [n,n+1]$ we have 
$$
g(x) \ge A_n e^{k_n (1-(x-n)^2)} \ge A_n e^0 = A_n 
$$
To prove $g$ is entire, it suffices to show that (1) converges locally uniformly on $\mathbb C$. Take a disk $D(a,1)$ with center $a\in \mathbb C$. When $|n|>100(|a|+1)$, the  argument of $z-n$ is close to either $0$ or $\pi$, for every $z\in D(a,1)$. This gives an estimate 
$$
\operatorname{Re}( k_n (1-(z-n)^2))  \le -\frac12 k_n n^2 
$$
(I omit boring details), hence
$$
\left|A_n e^{k_n (1-(z-n)^2)}\right| \le A_n e^{-\frac12 k_n n^2} <2^{-|n|}
$$
 proving uniform convergence on $D(a,1)$.

Comment: Excellent, thanks !!